# primeng p-multiselect dropdown filter search not showing no result found primeNG v-16.7.1

Tags: html, angular, frontend, primeng, angular-fullstack

I have added the primng p-multiselect and in that i have the filter in which i have search when the result is not found than the message not appearing[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUU1V.png) i am talking about this but in my case i am not getting any message

```
<p-multiSelect
        [options]="customerList"
        styleClass="multiSelectDropdown"
        containerStyleClass=""
        formControlName="customer"
        optionLabel="name"
        [filter]="true"
        filterPlaceHolder="Search..."
        placeholder="Select "
        (onFilter)="onFilter($event)"                   
                          >
getCustomerList(): void {
    const requestBody = {
      skip: 0,
      limit: 0,
    }
    this.customerService.getCustomerList(requestBody).subscribe({
      next: (response: any) => {
        this.customerList = response.customerList.map((item: any) => {
          return {
            name: item.name,
            id: item.id,
            email: item.email,
          }
        })
        this.filteredCustomerList = [...this.customerList]
      }
    })
  }

i have done using the ng template to filter the result and showing the display error message like
<ng-template pTemplate="empty">
                              <div *ngIf="filteredCustomerList.length === 0" class="empty-filter">
                                No results found
                              </div>
                            </ng-template>
onFilter(event:any){
    if (event){
      this.filteredCustomerList = this.customerList.filter(customer =>
        customer.name.toLowerCase().includes(event.filter.toLowerCase())
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: please share a stackblitz, with the issue replicated!

Answer (score 0):

Your `onFilter` method is not calling as there is no event to trigger when inputting.

Thus, the `filteredCustomerList` will remain the value same as you are initialized in `ngOnInit()`.

Also, the default filtering rule will be based on the property that you set for the `optionLabel`. Thus, you don't need the additional function to perform filtering.

Thus remove the `*ngIf="filteredCustomerList.length === 0"` will solve the issue.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="empty">
    <div class="empty-filter">
        No results found
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

So if you are keen to perform custom filtering, you need to add the `(onFilter)` event:

```
<p-multiSelect
        [options]="customerList"
        styleClass="multiSelectDropdown"
        containerStyleClass=""
        formControlName="customer"
        optionLabel="name"
        [filter]="true"
        filterPlaceHolder="Search..."
        placeholder="Select "                   
        (onFilter)="onFilter($event)">
   ...
</p-multiSelect>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/6rcwtk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fmulti-select-template-demo.html)

Comment: hi thanks i have added that forgot to mention above but still its not working

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in StackBlitz? Thanks. Otherwise, you should apply my first approach that without the `onFilter` event and remove the `*ngIf`.